# c++ serialization options

Tags: c++, qt, serialization, boost

I'm working in a project where I'm writing a plugin for a particular package.

This package implements a "new" method in one of its headers, and as such, I am unable to include `<strstream>` as it also implements "new".

The package sdk also includes a thinned out and very old version of boost, which means that I can't use the boost serialization classes. It is built on Qt for VS2008, and we are (required for this project) to be in VS2005, so I can't include Qt either.

I need to be able to get data from an externally running application, sending the data over TCPIP. What is the best way for me to serialize out the data from the source and read it back in with these limitations?

I'm currently tempted to make a struct which could contain all possible data that might be sent over, and then just copying the memory of that struct into a block of bytes which gets sent over, but this sounds like a bad approach to me.

Thanks,
Liron

Comment: try including <sstream>. strstream might be deprecated by your compiler

Comment: When you say <strstream> 'implements new', what exactly do you mean?
Cant you put the use of <strstream> in a separate compilation unit if you need it?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/66b85455-d667-44dc-adcb-1e1d2aa6f50b

I'm running into this problem, but the "new" implementation is in the sdk from the application we're trying to create a plugin for, so I can't remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

Answer (score 0):

[boost.serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) is the way to go here. It is the most comprehensible serialization library for C++ that I know of, and it comes with support for standard containers.

Comment: I do love and use Boost myself, but its serialization library is just a disaster.

Comment: Unfortunately, boost isn't an option for us, since the the SDK we're using is already including an old version of boost which doesn't include serialization.

Comment: @LKIM: You can always use two Boost libraries in one project, just go with static linking and that's it.

Comment: Not in this instance. We are already statically linking their SDK which is including the old boost.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the bytes from your data and pass it around, see a basic example.

```
QByteArray vectorToBin(const QVector<qint32> & vec)
{
    size_t size = sizeof(qint16);
    QByteArray result;
    foreach(qint16 e, vec) {
        for(int n = 0; n<=(size-1)*8; n+=8) {
            char c = static_cast<char>((e >> n));
            result.append(c);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

QVector<qint32> binToVector(const QByteArray & bytes)
{
    QVector<qint32> result;
    size_t size = sizeof(qint16);
    for(int i=0; i<bytes.size(); i+=size) {
        qint16 e = ((bytes[i+1] & 0xff)<<8) | (bytes[i] & 0xff);
        result << e;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: So that foreach will iterate over all the bytes of any random class that I want to serialize?

Comment: @LKIM no foreach iterates over a container, it's just an example. What you have to do is for a given object, take all the bytes of each attribute and mount a byte array. For primitive types you shift n times for n = 0, 8, 16 ... sizeof of the attribute. Repeat the process for attributtes that are objects instead of primitive types.  Be aware that is a lengthy process, the best way would be use a strstream or another serialization library.